# What are the unique benefits from each crafting skill in SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In SWTOR, the Cybertech skill gives you the ability to make bind-on-pickup speeders. This means that all cybertech crafters will have speeders which other crafters cannot have. Biochem crafters can use a special healing item which is not consumed upon use. Are there any other benefits to the users of those skills, and do other skills have similar benefits? If so, what are they?

Comment: I don't know any off the top of my head (Artifice doesn't seem to have any, at least), but BioWare have stated that they intend to adjust the crafting so that these bind-on-pickup items will probably be adjusted (so that crafters can sell them).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently only that Cybertech and Biochem have BOP craftable items.

Bioware has announced via interviews with devs and Bioware community leaders that they are imminently adjusting some of those Biochem stims, and at the same time adding more BOP items to all of the crafting [crew skills](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1330718831953&sqi=2&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http://www.swtor.com/info/systems/crew-skills&ei=aihRT6urMZHWiALazoG1Bg&usg=AFQjCNFIr6f1slI48Ru0v1JR8nIPiHZ7rA), so you aren't [forced to be Biochem during end game](http://tor.zam.com/story.html?story=28965) just to use those BOP stims to survive Hard mode flashpoints/operations. They want to make it so every crafting profession has something useful and unique at level 50.

Any discussion on the unique benefits of BOP craftable items at this point won't be applicable in a month or two.

UPDATE: Georg Zoeller (Bioware) recently [posted](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=3080439#edit3080439): "We're actually moving away from [BOP craftable items]. Most crafted items in the upcoming Game Update 1.2 will be freely tradeable."

Comment: Such is the way with ever changing MMO games.

Comment: yes, but in this particular case, the answer to this question will change very soon as it's already publicly announced and discussed.

Comment: I hate meeting people in open world PVP with those Biochem heals. Yet, I don't want to sacrifice my 400 in Artifice if something cool is coming up. :-)